# Regex for Array.replace(/ \]/g, ']')?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to trim a space after '[' and before ']'.

To trim a space after '[', `String.replace(/\[ /g, '[');` works;

however, to trim a space before  ']',  `String.replace(/ \]/g, ']');` seems not working.

What is the proper regex for that?

JavaScript.

Comment: Most likely because there are more collapsed white space before the "]". And assuming you meant `string.replace` instead of `Array`.

Comment: Nope that is not the case, and yes, I meant string.replace. I edit my Q. thanks

Comment: "trim a space before ']'", if you run `' ]'.replace(/ \]/g, ']') === ']'` gives the right result, assuming it was only one space and only one match for ' ]', your regex was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 str = str.replace(/\s+(\])|(\[)\s+/g, '$1$2');
```

Comment: str.replace(/(\[)\s+|\s+(\])/g, '$1$2'); works fine. Thanks